# KIvy on Ubuntu 14.04 is not the latest 1.10 dev even though I've run updates multiple times

Tags: ubuntu, installation, kivy, kivy-language

I've been running the same codes as listed in the kivy website on how to install kivy on ubuntu 14.04 (https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) and I got the nightly one installed because the stable one seems to only be 1.7 dev. However, the nightly one only give me 1.9.2 even though I ran the command for updates. I need 1.10.0 because I wrote the code on windows with kivy 1.10.0 and python 3.6.1, but I'm trying the code I wrote on my other ubuntu machine. When I try to run it, it says that certain modules can't be found like kivy._clock so I'm guessing it's because the kivy version on my ubuntu isn't up to date since it's 1.9.2. Can someone please let me know how to update it?

Comment: I will also add that package managers are not an instant connection to the source code of a project. You can expect that sometimes they will lag behind sometimes (even when it says nightly), maybe someone forgot to promote the nightly build or some such. If you truly require bleeding edge packages, you might need to build from source often.

Answer (score 0):

Unistall kivy from `apt` or your package manager and then

First try `pip install kivy@1.10.0`

If the pip wheel installs work, you probably don't need ubuntu package, however if it fails, you have more to do:

I appreciate you might not feel comfortable doing this, but you can build from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git
cd kivy
make install # possibly requires sudo I'm unsure
```

Let me know how it goes. This will install the very latest, you can also type:

```
git checkout <SOME branch/tag/commit you want>
```

Then you should be on a specific release, such as:

```
git fetch --all --tags --prune
git checkout tags/1.10.0
make install
```

It is possible you might need to run `make build` before `make install` hopefully this will get you to where you need to be.